# How to split a string based on second occurence of delimiter in Go?

Tags: string, go, split

I have a string `a_b_c_d_e`. I want to split it as `a_b` and `c_d_e`. What would be a good a way to do it?

Currently I know how to split a string based on first underscore by using the SplitN function:

`strings.SplitN(str, "_", 2)`

If str is `a_b_c_d_e` then output will be `a` and `b_c_d_e`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want doesn't exist, that I know of. So you just need to make your own:

```
package hello

func split(s string, sep rune, n int) (string, string) {
   for i, sep2 := range s {
      if sep2 == sep {
         n--
         if n == 0 {
            return s[:i], s[i+1:]
         }
      }
   }
   return s, ""
}
```

Comment: How about showing a simple usage of your function/solution?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a string `a_b_c_d_e`. I want to split it as `a_b` and `c_d_e`.

---

In the `strings` package there is a [`Cut`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings@latest) function

```
// Cut slices s around the first instance of sep,
// returning the text before and after sep.
// The found result reports whether sep appears in s.
// If sep does not appear in s, cut returns s, "", false.
```

Fork the code for the [`Cut`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/master:src/strings/strings.go) function as `Cut2`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

// Cut2 slices s around the second instance of sep,
// returning the text before and after sep.
// The found result reports whether sep appears twice in s.
// If sep does not appear twice in s, Cut2 returns s, "", false.
func Cut2(s, sep string) (before, after string, found bool) {
    if i := strings.Index(s, sep); i >= 0 {
        i += len(sep)
        if j := strings.Index(s[i:], sep); j >= 0 {
            i += j
            return s[:i], s[i+len(sep):], true
        }
    }
    return s, "", false
}

func main() {
    s := "a_b_c_d_e"
    fmt.Println(s)
    fmt.Println(Cut2(s, "_"))
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/6-OBBU70snQ

```
a_b_c_d_e
a_b c_d_e true
```